# Find epoch timestamp of Accurev file in my stream OR backing stream?

Tags: timestamp, epoch, accurev

I'm trying to find the epoch timestamp of whatever version of a file I get in my stream.

I tried "accurev hist -s stream_name -fx -t highest filename"

That only seems to work if the filename is in the default group of stream_name.  If stream_name inherits the file from a higher stream, I see "No history corresponding to selection."

I also tried "accurev stat -s stream_name -fe filename" to get the EID, and then used 
"-e EID" in the "accurev hist" command.  Again, this only works if the file is in the default group of stream_name, otherwise I get "No history corresponding to selection."

How can I get the timestamp regardless of whether the file is in my default group or in the default group of a parent stream?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command 'accurev stat -fix -s "streamname" "filename"'.

See example below, this will give you the last modified timestamp.

C:>accurev stat -fix -s demo /./dal.xml